# Where do file managers save their bookmarks?

Tags: file-manager

In pcmanfm and Thunar you can add bookmarks of folders to the left bar.

Are they stored somewhere in the filesystem as symlinks?

I´d like to use the bookmarks from other applications (terminal etc.), too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, (at least in `pcmanfm`) they are not stored as symlinks; they are stored in `.gtk-bookmarks`, a plain text file, like so:

```
file:///home/jason/Music Music
file:///home/jason/Videos Videos
```

Comment: I have both PCManFM and Thunar installed. The first because my OS is Lubuntu 12.10. Thunar was installed recently. As you pointed out `.gtk-bookmarks` stores the information bookmarked by PCManFM and it is read and used by Thunar as well.

Answer (score 19):

Here is some new information for Thunar, it recently (probably 2015-02) changed:

- previous location: `~/.gtk-bookmarks`
- current location: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`

Comment: This seems to be a still up-to-date answer. Supported format is `file:///home/user/Music Music`.